# connect and get to mysql

Tags: php, syntax

I have a table in an html page, I must fill it with data taken from a MySQL database. I am new to PHP scripting and I have got the following code:

```
<div class="Table" >
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td class="tab_sel">
                        -
                    </td>
                    <td class="tab_id">
                        Cod.ID
                    </td>
                    <td class="tab_name">
                        Nome
                    </td>
                    <td class="tab_cat">
                        Categoria
                    </td>
                    <td class="tab_price">
                        Prezzo al Pubblico
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        <input type="checkbox" name="html" value="html"/></input>
                    </td>  
                    <?php include "config.php"; $data = new Mysqlclass();
                     $data->connetti(); $post_sql = $data->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC"); 
                     if(mysql_num_rows($post_sql) > 0) 
                        {while($post_obj = $Data->estrai($post_sql))
                            {$id=$post_obj->id; 
                                $name = stripcslashes($post_obj->name); 
                                $cat = stripcslashes($post_obj->category);
                                $price= stripcslashes($post_obj->price);
                    echo "<td>".$id."</td>"n;
                    echo "<td>".$name."</td>"n;
                    echo "<td>".$cat."</td>"n;
                    echo "<td>".$price."</td>"n;
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo"Tabella vuota";
                    }
                    $data->disconnetti()
                    ?>
                </tr>
```

But when I execute the page it shows the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in D:\wamp\www\web-internal\pages\product.php on line 48.
```

Line 48 is the first echo: `"<td>".$id."</td>"n`; .

I need help to fill the table, and if it is possible to fill all the row in the database.

Comment: What is `n` doing at end of your line ? Do you mean by `\n` ?

Comment: replace the `n` with `<br>`

Comment: @YUNOWORK `<br>` within a table doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

```
  echo "<td>".$id."</td>"n;
```

but probably mean

```
  echo "<td>".$id."</td>\n";
```

Comment: Is there any need of '\n' in this program?? I think echo "<td>".$id."</td>"; is ok

Comment: Probably not, but I do think that this relates to what he wanted to do, i.e. put a line break there.

Comment: yeah, i think you are right according to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the n here

```
 echo "<td>".$id."</td>"n;
```

to

```
echo "<td>".$id."</td>\n";
```

or

```
echo "<td>".$id."</td><br />";
```